# Using hyperref for a citation

Tags: hyperref, citing

I need to cite a reference with a custom text.
However, I **cannot** make it work.
Please see the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

See \hyperref[ct1]{the post}.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{ct1} bkarpuz, Using hyperref for a citation, StackExchange, 2016.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

I am actually using \cite{ct1} together with other references of my manuscript in the numbered form somewhere in the text body. But in the abstract of the paper, journals want us to mention in the form [Journal, Vol, (Year), No, Pages] instead of [RefNo]. I am just trying to link it.

Comment: @Mico: I assume it's a typo -- it should be `\hyperref`, most likely

Comment: What's wrong with `\cite{ct1}` ??? That's automatically linked

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have mentioned my purpose at the end of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\renewcommand\citeleft{}  % no opening or closing brackets
\renewcommand\citeright{}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
See \cite{ct1}.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem[The post]{ct1} bkarpuz, Using hyperref for a citation, StackExchange, 2016.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am actually using \cite{ct1} together with other references of my manuscript in the numbered form somewhere in the text body. But in the abstract of the paper, journals want us to mention in the form [Journal, Vol, (Year), No, Pages] instead of [RefNo]. I am just trying to link it.

Comment: If you can use the `natbib` citation management package, you could define a citation "alias", i.e., an alternative form of the citation call-out. Please provide a reasonably realistic example of an entry that needs to be cited in two different ways. Please also provide Information as to whether you build the bibliography by Hand or with a tool such as BibTeX.