# Citation with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, citing, bibliographystyle, bibitem

[image: This is the citation style I would like.][image: Here is the output of the reference style I am getting.]

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308070/using-hyperref-for-a-citation) answer to cite using 'hyperref'. I want to retain this particular citation style but would like the references to be numbered as 1, 2, ... and not with the text in square brackets as given in the output. That is, the output shows that the 'References' list starts with [The post] followed by the name of the reference. But I would like it to be numbered.
Is there some way of achieving it?
Here is a part of an article I have typed using this format:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{authblk, amssymb, setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath, enumitem, pst-node, array, float, caption, graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\renewcommand\citeleft{}  
\renewcommand\citeright{}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\doublespacing
 \date{}
\title{\textbf{Post-quantum Cryptography using Entropic Quasigroups}}

\begin{document}

\section*{\centerline{1. Introduction}}\setcounter{section}{1}
It is a never-ending race to be one step ahead of adversaries in the pursuit of secure cryptographic algorithms and protocols. 
As quantum computing gains momentum, a number of cryptographic protocols relying on the mathematical concepts of number theory, group and field theory and Boolean algebra have become vulnerable to attacks. 
The focus is therefore shifting towards non-associative and non-commutative algebraic structures that may be able to withstand these attacks. 
In this paper, we discuss one such non-commutative and non-associative algebraic structure known as \emph{entropic} groupoids given in Gligoroski (\cite{Gligoroski1}) satisfying the \emph{palintropic} property which is also a quasigroup. 
Quasigroups have the ability to accommodate many cryptographically suitable properties (non-associativity, polynomial completeness to name a few) and especially, the number of possible quasigroups increases exponentially with an increase in their order, thus providing ample options to a cryptographer to choose the suitable ones for a particular cryptographic scheme (Schafer \cite{Schafer}). Quasigroup operations as in Markovski (\cite{Markovski}) are also useful in defining easy, fast and secure cryptographic functions.\\

\begin{thebibliography}{23}
\bibitem[2021a]{Gligoroski1}
\textbf{D. Gligoroski}, {\em Entropoid based cryptography.}, IACR Cryptology ePrint Archive 2021/469, (2021).
\bibitem[2015]{Markovski}
\textbf{S. Markovski}, {\em Design of crypto primitives based on quasigroups.}, Quasigroups Related Systems, \textbf{23} (2015), $41 - 90$.
\bibitem[2008]{Schafer}
\textbf{R. D. Schafer}, {\em An introduction to nonassociative algebras.}, The Project Gutenberg EBook (2008), EBook $\#$25156.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show a short compilable TeX code you have so far?

Comment: I have added a part of the article I have been typing using the given format.

Comment: Simply remove the optional argument of bibitem, then the citations will be numbered.

Answer (score 3):

This is a non-standard style request, so not something that is supported out of the box.

You can adjust these things by diving in to the internals of latex and its modifications by `hyperref`.  As standard `\bibitem[pkey]{key}entry` produces an bibliography item that has label given by `pkey` with a certain styling.  In your case you only want to use `pkey` in the text and wish to ignore this in the bibliography.  To do that we need to redifine the internal command that produces the bibliography entry, this is `\@lbibitem`.  We also wish to adjust the style of the printing of the numeric label, which is controlled by `\@biblabel`.  The `@` in both these names indicates these are internal commands.  Here are revised definitions that produce your style

```
\makeatletter
\def\@lbibitem[#1]#2{%
  \@skiphyperreftrue\H@item\@skiphyperreffalse
  \Hy@raisedlink{%
    \hyper@anchorstart{cite.#2\@extra@b@citeb}\relax\hyper@anchorend
  }%
  \if@filesw
      {\let\protect\noexpand
       \immediate
       \write\@auxout{\string\bibcite{#2}{#1}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
\def\@biblabel#1{#1.}
\makeatother
```

Putting this into a document gives

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{authblk, amssymb, setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath, enumitem, pst-node, array, float, caption, graphicx}
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\renewcommand\citeleft{}
\renewcommand\citeright{}

\titlelabel{\thetitle.\space}

\makeatletter
\def\@lbibitem[#1]#2{%
  \@skiphyperreftrue\H@item\@skiphyperreffalse
  \Hy@raisedlink{%
    \hyper@anchorstart{cite.#2\@extra@b@citeb}\relax\hyper@anchorend
  }%
  \if@filesw
      {\let\protect\noexpand
       \immediate
       \write\@auxout{\string\bibcite{#2}{#1}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
\def\@biblabel#1{#1.}
\makeatother

\doublespacing
\date{}
\title{Post-quantum Cryptography using Entropic Quasigroups}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

It is a never-ending race to be one step ahead of adversaries in the
pursuit of secure cryptographic algorithms and protocols.
As quantum computing gains momentum, a number of cryptographic
protocols relying on the mathematical concepts of number theory, group
and field theory and Boolean algebra have become vulnerable to
attacks.
The focus is therefore shifting towards non-associative and
non-commutative algebraic structures that may be able to withstand
these attacks.
In this paper, we discuss one such non-commutative and non-associative
algebraic structure known as \emph{entropic} groupoids given in
Gligoroski (\cite{Gligoroski1}) satisfying the \emph{palintropic}
property which is also a quasigroup.
Quasigroups have the ability to accommodate many cryptographically
suitable properties (non-associativity, polynomial completeness to
name a few) and especially, the number of possible quasigroups
increases exponentially with an increase in their order, thus
providing ample options to a cryptographer to choose the suitable ones
for a particular cryptographic scheme (Schafer
\cite{Schafer}). Quasigroup operations as in Markovski
(\cite{Markovski}) are also useful in defining easy, fast and secure
cryptographic functions.

\begin{thebibliography}{23}
\bibitem[2021a]{Gligoroski1} \textbf{D. Gligoroski}, \emph{Entropoid
  based cryptography}, IACR Cryptology ePrint Archive 2021/469,
  (2021).
\bibitem[2015]{Markovski} \textbf{S. Markovski}, \emph{Design of crypto
  primitives based on quasigroups}, Quasigroups Related Systems,
  \textbf{23} (2015), 41--90.
\bibitem[2008]{Schafer} \textbf{R. D. Schafer}, \emph{An introduction
  to nonassociative algebras}, The Project Gutenberg EBook (2008),
  EBook \#25156.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Note that I have added the `noadjust` option to the `cite` package, to remove the unwanted spaces.  I have also adjusted a number of other aspects of your code, to be more inline with standard LaTeX practise.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! I realised what needed to be done after going through your answer.